# Fatal process OOM in heap setup when running Node with Ulimit

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ulimit

I'm trying to limit the amount of ram available to my processes so I'm issuing a `ulimit -v 512000` command.

Running any `node` file however returns:

```
#
# Fatal process OOM in heap setup
#

Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I have tried running my `node` process with `--max_old_space_size=400` with no luck.

In case you want to replicate this just create a `test.js`:

```
console.log("Hello from ulimit test!")
```

and open a new terminal:

```
$ ulimit -v 512000
$ node test.js

#
# Fatal process OOM in heap setup
#

Illegal instruction (core dumped)

$ node --max_old_space_size=400 test.js 

#
# Fatal process OOM in heap setup
#

Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I'm running Node v8.10.0 on Ubuntu 18.

Comment: FWIW, can't reproduce on macOS. `node test.js` works

Answer (score 1):

`ulimit` limits the amount of virtual memory available and apparently node needs at least 1GB of it.

so if you run `ulimit -v 1024000` you can then run `node` but you only have access to `80mb` of memory.

and `--max_old_space_size=400` is basically useless.

Comment: Why only 80mb? `ulimit -v 1024000` should limit virtual memory to 1000MB, right? Are you saying that most of that will be used by node itself and there isn't much left for the JavaScript program?